# How to filter to only show System-Versioned tables in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2016

I am using SQL Server 2016 Management Studio. In my database I have lot of tables and some of them are System-Versioned tables. How can I filter the `Tables` list so that only System-Versioned tables are shown?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is possible. One solution would be to use a specific schema for those tables and use the filter function that management studio provides 
**or** 
add a prefix / suffix that identifies the table as a System Versioned table and filter on that prefix / suffix

Comment: I have to agree. I don't think it can be done out of the box, although now I wish it could be. I have the opposite problem: several databases with almost all system-versioned tables, and I'd love to be able find just the handful that are not. Wasn't a feature I knew I wanted until I saw someone ask for it....